# Ordering a Content-Item Query in Orchard

Tags: sorting, content-management-system, orchardcms

I have created a simple content-type in orchard, which contains (among other things) the stars module, which is based on the voting module (basically this enables the user to cast his vote for an article and then display the average result represented by stars). So far this works just fine, but now I want something like a top-10 list for my articles. I started with creating a query that gets all the items from this type, after that i wanted to order them by their average voting value and this is where things got tricky...

The sorts criteria page lets me pick all of my own content fields in this content item but no field from the voting module. I also took a look into the bindings to see if I can enable something there, but all I can find there are the fields from `Contrib.Voting.Models.VoteWidgetPartRecord` which does not contain any of the desired information.

I took a look in the database and discovered a table of this name that this table contains the information which content items use the voting plugin - what I would need instead is the information from the table `Contrib_Voting_ResultRecord`.

Is there something I just did not see, to get this working? I believe I cannot be the first one to want this kind of feature. Or do I have to code the sort criteria myself, and if so where can I find any information about how to do so?

Comment: And the voting module itself doesn't provide that capability?